# Crossdomain request and plain javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, jsonp

On a website `AAA.com` will include a javascript from website `BBB.com` which has to be non blocking execution script.

The javascript grabbed on `BBB.com` will extract the `meta keywords`, the `meta title` from `AAA.com` and it'll be sending those data to a particular url to website `BBB.com`

The `BBB.com` website will be sending back an url for a video player.

I guess i'll have problem because this is clearly a crossdomain request, which i wanted to solve with an `JSON-P` request, but the problem is that we can't use `jQuery`.

How would you achieve that please ?

Comment: You really don't need jQuery to make JSONP requests!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132796/how-to-make-a-jsonp-request-from-javascript-without-jquery

Comment: jQuery just exposes existing functionality; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/please-explain-jsonp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first script from BBB.com will have to parse the keywords, serialize them into a URL query and dynamically create a second `<script>` tag that loads content from BBB.com (this is how you will get around the SOP restriction).

The content from BBB.com would typically be a call to some function inside the first script that knows how to consume the content.

For example, the first script might read like

```
function showVideoPlayer(parameters) {
   // ...
}

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://bbb.com/crossdomain?'; // includes serialized meta keywords
// and now append script to e.g. the body so that the request is made
```

And the content returned would be

```
showVideoPlayer({param1: "value1", param2: "value2"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither JSON-P, nor CORS have any slight relevance to jQuery. Which also happens to be library written in Javascript and therefore can never possibly do anything Javascript itself can't.

Also, your scenario doesn't looks like it needs any crossdomain requests at all. Just have on your AAA.com page something like `<script src="http://BBB.com/script.js"></script>` and it will work, because `<script>` tag does not impose any origin limitations and never did. Use dynamically created `<iframe>` and/or `<form>` tags to asynchronously submit results back to BBB.com as `POST` or pretty much anything with `src` (`<img>`,`<script>`) to submit them as `GET`.