# How to rewrite jquery to javascript: JsonP+ Callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

How would one rewrite this jquery function as regular javascript?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://192.168.1.103:8124/',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "_testcb",
        cache: false,
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#test").append(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Particularly

```
  jsonpCallback: "_testcb",
         cache: false,
```

Original Wrong Question:
**How does one set the properties of an xmlhttprequest object to recieve JsonP callbacks using regular javascript?**

Updated Correct Question: 
**How does one make JsonP Callbacks with "Pure Javascript"?**

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code conversion tool. Do you have a particular question?

Comment: Search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery

Comment: It's more about adopting properties set by the above jquery function... I will provide an example.

Comment: @zerkms Question Updated. I'd rather learn how to fish than be given one:)

Comment: If you want an absolute minimal jsonp component check out component.io jsonp https://github.com/LearnBoost/jsonp/blob/master/index.js

Comment: A cross-domain jsonp request doesn't use xmlhttprequest, it creates a script element. (jQuery hides that from you to make it easy to use.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send a request and see what it looks like through your browser's web developer tools:

[image]

So to mimic jQuery's anti-caching behavior, you can append a timestamp parameter to the URL when sending an AJAX request:

```
jsonp(url + '&_=' + (new Date).getTime());
```

As for the JSONP callback, you just pass a `callback` parameter:

```
jsonp(url + '?callback=' + callback_name);
```

The browser then basically calls `eval(callback_name + '(' + response + ')');`, so make sure that your callback function is global.

Comment: Aha! A callback parameter...

Comment: Is that the   jsonpCallback: "_testcb", in the above sample?

Comment: @DudeSolutions: Yep, see my screenshot. It may be a little hard to read, but the jQuery source file isn't too complicated: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/jsonp.js

Comment: JSONP isn't just a matter of adding a callback parameter - isn't it normally implemented by appending a script element rather than using an xmlhttprequest? At least, for cross-domain requests. (jQuery does this for you, does it not?)

Comment: @nnnnnn: I think that's the only way you can do it.

Comment: @nnnnnn I can't use jQuery. I have to use the "pure" javascript equivalent of my example to get it to work server side.

Comment: @DudeSolutions: Why? Are you using Node?

Comment: @Blender Not Node-- PhantomJs :)

Comment: @DudeSolutions - I know you don't want jQuery, I was just indicating that jQuery hides this implementation detail from you but it is what you will have to implement for yourself.

Comment: @DudeSolutions: You can include jQuery in PhantomJS: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Page-Automation#use-jquery-and-other-libraries

Comment: @Blender From what I have tried Jquery can only be used to manipulate DOM objects scraped by PhantomJs- it won't compile to the runtime code.Long story short: I just want to send POST or GET data from my phantomJs app to other servers at other domains I own, to send data to various controllers at other websites.

Comment: @nnnnnn Sure enough- you're 100% right. A script is indeed appended. In the example below, a script is appended to the HEAD. See below.

Comment: A lot of concepts to grok- really, I was asking the wrong question... Here is another question that more accurately reflects what I'm trying to do....: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241615/curl-or-the-equivalent-of-for-server-side-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Update:

So after a little digging I found the equivalent from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132796/how-to-make-a-jsonp-request-from-javascript-without-jquery):

```
function foo(data)
{
    // do stuff with JSON
}

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = '//example.com/path/to/jsonp?callback=foo'

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
// or document.head.appendChild(script) in modern browsers
```

Works like a charm!