# Curl: Or the equivalent of - For Server Side Javascript

Tags: node.js, curl, phantomjs

Popular scripting languages such as Python and PHP have extensions that utilize the Curl library- but little documentation exists for the newer Javascript server side languges.

I was wondering --is there a library or hack that can mimic the behavior of Curl in server side Javascript frameworks such as NodeJs and PhantomJs?

If no: how can Curl-like requests be made in NodeJs? Or PhantomJs?

**Also -and most importantly:**

Is there a "pure javascript" implementation that could work in the runtime of any server-side Javascript framework?

Comment: https://npmjs.org/package/node-curl

Comment: @cababunga Never seen this one- thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node.js has an HTTP client in its core library.

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Comment: **Palm to forehead**  Simple enough!

Comment: Also, the [request](https://npmjs.org/package/request) module is a popular (easier) way to use the core http library.