# Widget cross domain ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

We have a widget for clients to put onto their website. This widget needs to make a call to our website to validate some data entered by the user. However, ajax calls are domain bound, so calling from the clients webpage to our webpage is not allowed.

How can i make a request from any site to my own?

There is a way, i'm sure. For example, Facebook, with it's user hosted like button, probably also makes a request to their own website.

**EDIT**

i am using XMLHTTP for this

Without enabling any options on the client website.

Comment: I've had great success with using the d3 jsonp functions https://gist.github.com/tmcw/4494715.  All you need to do is change the 'namespace' on them and they are in native JS

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your data type to 'jsonp', as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3506306/382456).  Although that answer is in jQuery, it is [still possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132796/how-to-make-a-jsonp-request-from-javascript-without-jquery), although slightly more difficult.  I don't want to be one of "those guys", but in this case it's easier to use jQuery.