# how to load json from url using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript which should be really simple to solve, but I am lost as of now.

I have a url: http:getall.json
Using JavaScript (not JQuery or php. Just JavaScript), I want to read this JSON string and      parse it. That's it.

Comment: it may helpful for you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743186/get-json-array-with-pure-js

Comment: The url you have provided throws an error and doesn't return any JSON string. Some PHP Session stuff crash. Also if you want to be able to make cross domain AJAX calls the remote server should explicitly allow CORS or support JSONP. Is this the case?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov why is that so? i can access the url.

Comment: Yes, me too, except that it doesn't return JSON but some PHP error. Maybe you need to be authenticated in order to be able to call it. It this the case? Try opening it in a new private browser tab and you will see the error.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov i've edited my question and paste the json that im getting from the url

Comment: Unfortunately you seem to be the only one not getting an error when calling this url. Anyway, does this endpoint support CORS? If it doesn't you will not be able to make a cross domain AJAX call to it. In this case you might need to call it from your server side script.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov will you show me how to get that json when i test the code in jsfiddle.net using purely javascript only? by the way thanks for your reply! :)

Comment: I cannot show you because this url doesn't work for me. It crashes with a PHP error. Besides you are not answering my question whether this endpoint supports CORS. Because if it doesn't you cannot make an AJAX call to it. As far as making an AJAX call is concerned, then MamaWalter already provided you an answer. But it won't work if the endpoint doesn't support CORS.

Comment: i can't contact the server now. and honestly i dont know what CORS is. if i try to upload this json to a free server for testing will u be able to help me? thanks!

Comment: If you don't know what CORS is then I very strongly recommend you read about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing Otherwise you will not be able to make cross domain AJAX requests. And of course that we will help you if you provide an endpoint that works and which supports CORS.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov i know how to parse json, my only problem is i dont know how to get a json from URL. do you have any sample code that i can test? thanks!

Comment: Yes, there are already 2 answers to your questions showing how to make an AJAX request. Except that they won't work if the endpoint you are calling doesn't support CORS. So the first thing that should be done is to ensure that the server side script that is returning this JSON sets the proper CORS response headers in order to allow cross domain calls. I very strongly suggest you reading about CORS first.

Comment: thanks @DarinDimitrov but i dont need ajax request, i need a purely javascript request

Comment: thanks @DarinDimitrov but i dont need ajax request, i need a purely javascript request

Comment: AJAX is pure javascript. The 2 answers that were provided use the native `XMLHttpRequest` object and do not rely on any framework such as jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

access to your url doesn't work, you should show the `JSON` result. In javascript to get JSON object with `AJAX` request you can do something like this:

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest;
request.open('GET', 'http://v-apps-campaign.com/dunkindonuts/main/get_allStore', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400){
    // Success!
    data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
  } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  // There was a connection error of some sort
};

request.send();
```

your result will be in the `data` variable.

Comment: thanks for the answer! but i tested this code in jsfiddle.net but it doesn't give me the result? what should i do? thanks!

Comment: all i want is to see the json result if i paste it in jsfiddle?

Comment: It doesn't work because the url you provided doesn't return JSON but it returns some PHP error. Also you cannot make cross domain AJAX calls unless the remote server explicitly allows it.

Answer (score 1):

**JSONP** calls:

```
function getJSONP(url, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    var callbackName = "jsonpcallback_" + new Date().getTime();
    window[callbackName] = function (json) {
        callback(json);
    };
    script.src = url + (url.indexOf("?") > -1 ? "&" : "?") + 'callback=' + callbackName;

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
getJSONP("http://v-apps-campaign.com/dunkindonuts/main/get_allStore", function(jsonObject){
    //jsonObject is what you want
});
```

**Regular ajax ajax** call:

```
function getXHR() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    try {
        return new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0');
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            // The fallback.
            return new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
        } catch (e) {
            throw new Error("This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest.");
        }
    }
}

function getJSON(url, callback) {
    req = getXHR();
    req.open("GET", url);
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var jsonObject = null,
                status;
            try {
                jsonObject = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                status = "success";
            } catch (e) {
                status = "Invalid JSON string[" + e + "]";
            }
            callback(jsonObject, status, this);
        }
    };
    req.onerror = function () {
        callback(null, "error", null);
    };
    req.send(null);
}
getJSON("http://v-apps-campaign.com/dunkindonuts/main/get_allStore", function (jsonObject, status, xhr) {
    //jsonObject is what you want
});
```

I tested these with your **url** and it seems like you should get the data with a **jsonp** call, because with regular ajax call it returns:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

with **jsonp** it gets the data but the data is not a valid json, it seems your server side has some **php errors**:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

...
```

Comment: hi @Mehran Hatami i tested your code in jsfiddle.net but it wont give me the result and i also edited this part getJSON("yourjsonurl.json", function (jsonObject, status, xhr) {
    alert (jsonObject);
});

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML include your json file and a js code as modules

```
<script src="/locales/tshared.js"  type="module"  ></script>
<script src="/scripts/shared.js" type="module"  ></script>
```

file content of tshared

```
export const loc = '{"en": { "key1": "Welcome" },"pt": {"key1": "Benvindo"} }'
file content of shared
import {loc} from "./../../locales/tshared.js";
var locale = null;
locale = JSON.parse(loc) ;
```

Adapt path and names as needed, use locale at will.