# JavaScript + JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I got this JSON format dataset in a file `data.json`:

```
{
    "timestamp": "Wed Apr 02 2014, 19:03:19",

    "test": [   
        441.02,
        null,
        null,
        460.99,
        485.91,
        501.0,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    ],

    "test1": [
        437.0,
        null,
        null,
        464.989,
        488.52,
        499.996,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    ]
}
```

And I need to push that values to an `array[]` in JavaScript to get something like:

```
var test = [441.02, null, null, 460.99, 485.91, 501.0, null, null, null, null]
```

```
var test1 = [437.0, null, null, 464.989, 488.52, 499.996, null, null, null, null]
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?
I'm a JavaScript newbie.

Comment: did you mean var test = [441,523,null,null]?

Comment: [a guide on javascript basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) is probably the right direction, amirite? lolol

Comment: I meant var test = [441.002,null,null,460.99,485.91,501.0,null,null,null]
All the values in test, etc etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must load the JSON and then parse it using `JSON.parse()`:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    me = this,
    test = null,
    test1 = null;

// Note: change data.json to any JSON file
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'data.json', true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // If you got something from the request
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        // Parse the JSON from data.json
        var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        me.test = obj.test;
        me.test1 = obj.test1;

        // Do manipulation here. You can call to other functions here.
        doOtherStuff();
    }
};

// Send the request to get the data
xmlhttp.send(null);

function doOtherStuff() {
    console.log(me.test); // This will work because it is called from inside the function
}
```

**References:**

[Get Json Array with pure JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743186/get-json-array-with-pure-js) and [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript).

**NOTE:** You must do *all* data manipulation inside of the `if` statement inside the `onreadystatechange` function because the request is asynchronous. The `onreadystatechange` function is only fired when the ready state is changed. The if statement is only true if you get data from the request. If you try to access the data from outside `if` statement, it will not work. Here's a little diagram showing why:

```
   Request Made using xmlhttp.send(null)
|--Code after xmlhttp.send(null) is executed
|  Request complete
|  Request onreadystatechange function is called (readyState = 4 && status = 200)
v
v
v (Code continues to execute)
```

Notice how the code after `xmlhttp.send(null)` will probably be executed before the request is complete? That's why you must do the data manipulation inside the `onreadystatechange` function.

**EDIT:** To make the array globally accessible, declare it in a global scope, then set it inside the `onreadystatechange` function. Call any functions that need `test` from inside the `onreadystatechange` function. (See above edits to code.)

Comment: After that piece of code im doing:
console.log(test) to see if I got the array, but im getting:
test is undefined.
How can iterate trough the elements in that array?.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you doing `console.log(test)` after `xmlhttp.send(null);`?

Comment: Exactly

xmlhttp.send(null);

console.log(test);

Comment: @mdv see my updates. You must do the data manipulation inside the function because the request is made asynchronously.

Comment: If I do console.log(test) inside onreadystatechange I got: "undefined" in the console, how can I iterate the values to push them in an array?.
thanks!

Comment: It must be inside the `if` statement.

Comment: wait, was my bad, I was reading the wrong file.
Thank you so much jsve, its resolved :D

Comment: Are you doing this from your Plunker project? If so, I don't see a `graphs.json` file.

Comment: You cant look at it now: http://plnkr.co/edit/QmPqWZhKgr0PvsgqAoqT
One more thing, how can I make an globaly accesible array so I can use the values pushed further in all my js file?.
Thanks!

Comment: Updated. (Note: put everything inside of the `if` statement inside of the function.)

Comment: @mdv Glad to be of service.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your JSON is associated with a variable named `obj`, you can do the following:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    eval(key + " = " + array[obj]);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Alternative:

```
keys = Object.keys(obj)
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    eval(keys[i] + " = " + obj[keys[i]]);
}
```

Comment: Note: `eval()` could be evil in some situations. (See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil)).

Answer (score 0):

If you have alot of tests

```
var tests = [];
var jsonLength = json.length;
var key;
for(key in json){
    if(typeof json[key] === "object"){
        tests.push(json[key]);
    }
}

var test1 = tests[0];
var test2 = tests[1];
```