# Ajax POST in javascript without jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, post

I need to consume a JSON object from the server side from an URL which I have to create in the client side(Javascript) using ajax POST.

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", url, true);
oReq.responseType = "json";
oReq.onload = function(e) {
    var jsonObj = oReq.response;
   /* ... */
}
```

What am I supposed to use inside the `function(e)`?

I am not supposed to use Jquery here.

Comment: I used this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132796/how-to-make-a-jsonp-request-from-javascript-without-jquery for the same issue. Your server must support JSONP though

Comment: chouck out this http://blog.mgechev.com/2011/07/21/ajax-jquery-beginners/

Answer (score 1):

You need to `send()` your request.

See [this (slightly adjusted) example:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.open("POST", url, true);
oReq.responseType = "json";
oReq.onload = function(e) {
  var jsonResponse = oReq.response; // not responseText
  /* ... */
}
oReq.send();
```

Comment: I want to do a post here in a url.

Comment: If you want to post, put the content you want to post in the `.send`. This is the correct response.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a function i wrote & always use for ajax requests,posts... whatever

```
 function ajax(a,b,e,d,f,g,c){
  // url,callback,type(get),FormData(null),uploadProgress,progress 
  c=new XMLHttpRequest;
  !f||(c.upload.onprogress=f);
  !g||(c.onprogress=g);
  c.onload=b;
  c.open(e||'get',a);
  c.send(d||null)
 }
```

I think that only chrome supports the `responseType='json';`
by removeing `responseType='json';` you can get the json response by using

```
JSON.parse()
```

so:

```
JSON.parse(oReq.response)
```

to get the response from this ajax call you can choose between 3 ways

1.In my case / or your

```
c.response
//your
oReq.response
```

2.Using this

```
this.response // i always use this.
```

3.e.target

```
e.target.response
```

**ajax function description:**

This ajax function has 6 usable parameters

url, callback, type(get or post),FormData(or null),uploadProgress,progress

only 2 are necessary `url` and `callback` (simple get request)

```
ajax('url',function(){console.log(this.response)})
// it's better to use a function reference to avoid memory leaks
// like
function cb(){console.log(this.response)};
ajax('url',cb)
```

in your case you use post

so you need 4 parameters

`url`, `callback`, `type(post in your case)`, and the `formdata`

so:

```
ajax('url',callbackFunction,'post',fd);
```

where `fd` is build in 2 ways

```
var fd=new FormData();
fd.append('key','value');
ajax('url',callbackFunction,'post',fd);
```

or you can also post the whole form

```
var fd=new FormData(document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]);
ajax('url',callbackFunction,'post',fd);
```

alternatively you can also add a progress event function

```
function progress(e){
 console.log(e.loaded/e.total*100)
}
```

same for the  upload progress

and the callback function is something like that

```
function callbackFunction(e){
console.log(e.target.response);
console.log(this.response);
console.log(c.response);

// without the reponsetype

console.log(JSON.parse(e.target.response));
console.log(JSON.parse(this.response));
console.log(JSON.parse(c.response))
}
```

if you have any questions just ask.