# Changing ajax jquery request to a XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this Ajax request with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pageName;

    $('li a').on('click', function (){
        pageName = $(this).attr('data-url');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://mywebsite.com/' + pageName + '/?json=1',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {
                var page = data.content;
                $('.mypage').html(page);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

And i want change to XMLHttpRequest, so i did this:

```
function showPage () {

    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById('.mypage').innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
        }
    };

    var attr = document.getElementByTagName(this);
    var pageName = attr.getAttribute('data-url');
    var url = 'http://mywebsite.com/' + pageName + '/?json=1',

    httpRequest.open('GET', url);
    httpRequest.send();
}
```

It's not working at all, anyone knows what i did wrong?

Comment: open(method,url,async) 
Specifies the type of request, the URL, and if the request should be handled asynchronously or not.

method: the type of request: GET or POST
url: the location of the file on the server
async: true (asynchronous) or false (synchronous)

you missing one parameter in open() function

Comment: the 3rd argument to open() defaults to true if omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
document.getElementById('.mypage').innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
```

A selector beginning with `.` is a class selector, not an ID. It should be:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('mypage')[0].innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
```

I'm assuming you only have one element with this class. If there are multiple, you need to change that to a loop that sets them all.

However, you can't use XMLHttpRequest with JSONP dataType. See

[JavaScript XMLHttpRequest using JsonP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780430/javascript-xmlhttprequest-using-jsonp)

for how to implement JSONP with raw Javascript.

Comment: That should be getElement**s**ByClassName