# How to wrap jsonP callback in native javascript Promise?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp, es6-promise

I'm playin with native Promise to combine a bunch of XmlHttpRequests into one result and I think I got it working, see http://jsfiddle.net/pjs06hdo/
(random calls to flickr api, see the console for what's actually going on in which order)

There might be shorter implementations but with this code I can understand what's going on.

But then there comes the stupid JSONP :-( as it turns out the actual target site does not allow Cross-site requests and I have to use a provided jsonP endpoint (again simulated with flickr) And here I'm stuck: that stupid global callback does not fit into my basic understanding of `Promise`

I think the solution has to do with explanations in [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises).

I tried to implement this but it works only partially: http://jsfiddle.net/b33bj9k1/ There is no actual output, only console messages, sorry. But there you can see that there are three calls to create the promises but the `resolve()`, the `jsonFlickrApiAsync()` gets called only once.

What would be the right way to handle jsonP callbacks with Promise so I can have an `Promise.all()` to deal with the results as in the XmlHttpRequest version above?

No jQuery please - I want to understand whats really going

Comment: I don't think you can use a `promise` with jsonp. Check out [this similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780430/javascript-xmlhttprequest-using-jsonp)

Comment: I think this question is rather unrelated @KJPrice I know that i cannot call jsonP service with xmlhttprequest. There is no mention of `````Promise`````at all?

Comment: You have to use different callback names each time you make a JSONP request - otherwise function for the last one will overwrite the function for the first one before the response for the first one has been received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem with promises, this is a problem with [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Since it uses global callbacks, you need to use different callbacks - with different names - for each request. For Flickr that means you have to use [their `jsoncallback` url parameter](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html). The parameter name may vary for your actual endpoint.

---

However, your use of promises is indeed weird. Typically you'd use one promise per request, to represent that request's result. You are intentionally creating only one global promise, which cannot work.

```
function loadJSONP(url, parameter="callback") {
    var prop = "loadJSONP.back" + loadJSONP.counter++;
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    function withCleanUp(r) {
        return (x) => {
            loadJSONP[prop] = null;
            document.head.removeChild(script);
            r(x);
        }
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        loadJSONP[prop] = withCleanUp(resolve);
        script.onerror = withCleanUp(reject);
        // setTimeout(script.onerror, 5000); might be advisable

        script.src = url+"&"+parameter+"="+prop;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    });
}
loadJSONP.counter = 0;
```