# Why wikipedia ajax call is not working

Tags: javascript, json

```js
var url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&limit=15&search=' + search;
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

ourRequest.open('GET', url);

ourRequest.onload = function() {
  var data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
  console.log(data);
};
ourRequest.send();
```

Can someone tell me why i am not able to get parsed data in my console.

Comment: you're missing `ourRequest.send();` before onload.

Comment: [Open your DevTools and look for an error](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). It might be a CORS error.

Comment: So did you mean  ourRequest.send(); should be after ourRequest.open('GET', url);

Comment: E.Sundin I am sry, I guess i need to learn DevTools. I am a newbie.

Comment: I've just tested and it's working.

Comment: There's always something to learn. Also, I don't think the `send()` call should be moved at all.

Comment: Is the `search` variable defined?

Comment: Yes.Its the input of a text area

Comment: Related, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780430/javascript-xmlhttprequest-using-jsonp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add one more parameter to your url variable to make this request work -
**origin=***. Add it and your code will be fine.

Check how I've changed the `url` variable. Wikipedia API requires the request origin included in the parameters string.

```js
document.getElementById('do-search').addEventListener('click', search);

function search(){
  var search = document.getElementById('search').value;
  var url='http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&limit=15&origin=*&search='+search;
  var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

  ourRequest.open('GET', url);

  ourRequest.onload = function() {
    var data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = data;
  };
  ourRequest.send();
}
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text">

<button id="do-search">Search</button>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i made it to work with the following code.

```
$.ajax({
url: url,
jsonp: "callback",
dataType: "jsonp",
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data);
 }
 });
```