# How to Display JSON data from another site

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have a page where is some of JSON data stored like this

```
{
    "video": {
        "user": {
            "first_name": "Curtis",
            "last_name": "Shoch"
        },
        "name": "Darwin Digital",
        "location": "Kennesaw",
        "video_type": "c",
        "created": "2018-01-16T13:11:11.326636Z"
    }
}
```

I need to take this data and display it on another page, o I tried to do something like this

```
var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        callback(null, xhr.response);
      } else {
        callback(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
};
getJSON('https://dev.truthify.com/api/deeplink/info/bf76b0bd-5210-4c55-af23-c9689ffec536/', function(err, data) {
  if (err != null) {
    alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
  } else {
    result.innerText = video.name;
  }
```

But I got a message

> No Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Header is present on the requested resource because I am using source from another website and it is blocked. So is there any why to bypass this, or some other way to take this data.

Comment: Use CORS extension google chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript XMLHttpRequest using JsonP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780430/javascript-xmlhttprequest-using-jsonp)

Comment: Did you try to google this? Your error message should give you millions of results.

Comment: Of course that I did. I tried several options, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting and json and try to send it in another url in a different origin domain.
In order to access a server on different origin domain  u have to make a cors request (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) .
This  means you have to set an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header  in order for your client agent to gain permission  on the server.