# Problems with express and CORS

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I am running a nodejs script with express.
I have read [the documentation](https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html) but I can't make CROS requests still.
I am running a web server to show how it is not working: http://a56f1bae.ngrok.io/

I really do not know why it is not working, it is almost exactly as it is in the documentation.

Here is my script if that helps:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
})

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.send(html);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Server running on port 3000');
});



var html = `
<html>
<head>
<script>
var url = 'https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&hl=en&q=test';
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if('withCredentials' in request) {
     // Firefox 3.5 and Safari 4
     try{
       request.open('GET', url, false);
       request.send();
       document.write('It is doing fine!');
     } catch (err){
       document.write(err)
     }
  } else if (XDomainRequest) {
     // IE8
     try{
       var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
       xdr.open('get', url);
       xdr.send();
       document.write('It is doing fine!');
     } catch (err){
       document.write(err)
     }
     // handle XDR responses -- not shown here :-)
  }
</script>
</head>
</html>
`;
```

Thank you so much and sorry if my question is obviously.

Comment: localhost:3000 is not running, can't check the error. or please post the network panel log

Comment: I have just restarted it. Sorry. It should be running now.

Comment: Can you have a complete code? Is this the complete code?

Comment: now it is complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a conceptual problem.

You have to set cors header to the SERVER not the CLIENT.
You want to access `suggestqueries.google.com` from `localhost:3000`. That means in this case the server is Server is google.com or I guess `google API`. That means you need to set the cors there, in the google api.

If let's say you had an app running in `localhost:someport` and access `localhost:3000` which may serve as api service, then you needed to add cors to your Express app. Because then it would have been your SERVER.

Check this out: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors

Note: For development purpose you can disable same origin policy in chrome. refer here on how to do that: [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

**Edit: A workaround**
As there are very little docs for google suggest, You can use `jsonp` to overcome the cors issue. check: [JavaScript XMLHttpRequest using JsonP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780430/javascript-xmlhttprequest-using-jsonp)

Instead using `XMLHttpRequest` try using the `jsonp` function created by @paul

> ```
> function jsonp(url, callback) {
>     var callbackName = 'jsonp_callback_' + Math.round(100000 * Math.random());
>     window[callbackName] = function(data) {
>         delete window[callbackName];
>         document.body.removeChild(script);
>         callback(data);
>     };
>
>     var script = document.createElement('script');
>     script.src = url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + 'callback=' + callbackName;
>     document.body.appendChild(script);
> }
>
> jsonp('http://www.helloword.com', function(data) {
>    alert(data);
> });
> ```

Comment: I think there is nothing in Google API about Google suggestions.

Comment: Your workaround is perfect! Thank you so much for helping me!