# Javascript JsonP syntax error when using previous example

Tags: javascript, jsonp

This is a follow up to this question:
[JavaScript XMLHttpRequest using JsonP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780430/javascript-xmlhttprequest-using-jsonp)

I was trying to experiment with JsonP, since I'm trying to find a replacement for using a Cors proxy. I tried the example listed in the 2nd answer of the linked question but I got this error:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Learn More] www.google.com:1

Why is that?

The code used:

```
function jsonp(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let script = document.createElement('script')
        const name = "_jsonp_" + Math.round(100000 * Math.random());
        //url formatting
        if (url.match(/\?/)) url += "&callback="+name
        else url += "?callback="+name
        script.src = url;

        window[name] = function(data) {
            resolve(data);
            document.body.removeChild(script);
            delete window[name];
        }
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    });
}

var data = jsonp("https://www.google.com");
data.then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: It's a zero-score answer by a 1-rep user. Doesn't work because `https://www.google.comcallback=jsonp_12345` returns a document

Comment: @CertainPerformance so in which line will the issue arise? and what is the problem with a returned document?

Comment: A document is not JSONP. You need to find an endpoint which serves JSONP.

Comment: @CertainPerformance When you say it returns a document, you mean an html page?

Comment: Yes, eg trying to parse `<!doctype...` as Javascript doesn't work.

Comment: @CertainPerformance do you happen to know of some api somewhere which returns a jsonp string?