# How to define jsonp callback in prototype javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate widget through javascript, that fetch the result from the server and display it.

This is how i am doing:

```
var Widgets = function( element, options ) {

    this.ele = document.getElementById( element );
    this.options = extend({}, this.options);
    extend( this.options, options );
    this._init();
};

Widgets.prototype = {
    options: {
        userKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }, 
    _init: function() {

        // Send request to Server
        this.sendRequestToServer();
    }, 

    sendRequestToServer: function() {

        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'http://example.localhost/api/get_widget/'+this.options.userKey+'?callback=onFetchComplete';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }, 

    // callback not working
    onFetchComplete: function() {

    }

};
```

My problem is `callback=onFetchComplete`, my method in not callable with callback request. I know that this will work with when i call with `this.onFetchComplete`. Can anyone please suggest the right way to do this through the same prototyping approach?

Comment: How did you instantiate the `Widgets`?

Comment: Do you know [how JSONP works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)? There is no global `onFetchComplete` variable that could be called.

Comment: @Bergi this is how do i initiate `new Widgets('cf_widget_container');`

Comment: @Bergi is there any alternative way with prototype?

Comment: Yes and no. You somehow need to find a way to generate a unique global identifier for each request callback. You *might* use the instance (if its a global variable already) and directly call the prototype method, as in `?callback=mywidgets.onFetchComplete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser looks in the global scope for the callback function so you would need to define `onFetchComplete` in the global scope. It looks quite nasty but you could do this:

> `sendRequestToServer: function() {
>       var script = document.createElement('script');
>       window.onFetchComplete = this.onFetchComplete;
>       script.src = http://example.localhost/api/get_widget/'+this.options.userKey+'?callback=onFetchComplete';
>       document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
>   },`

This is a quick-and-dirty solution so you might want to find a more elegant solution to set scope when dealing with [jsonp in pure javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132796/how-to-make-a-jsonp-request-from-javascript-without-jquery).

Comment: Notice this would have the wrong `this` context of the invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
script.src = 'http://example.localhost/api/get_widget/'+this.options.userKey+'?callback=Widgets.onFetchComplete';
```

I tested with this code :

```
Widgets = {
    options: {
        userKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }, 
    _init: function() {

        // Send request to Server
        this.sendRequestToServer();
    }, 

    sendRequestToServer: function() {

        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'http://api.dribbble.com/players/simplebits?callback=Widgets.onFetchComplete';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }, 

    // callback not working
    onFetchComplete: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

};

window.onload = function() {
    var w = Widgets._init();
}
```

Comment: Why does this work? What exactly did you change? Why is `Widgets` not a function any more?

Comment: First of all its working because I have set the callback function to : Widgets.onFetchComplete, secondly I was getting an error the way you have created the object, so I decided to do it the old fashion way. You should also have a look at : http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/ , prototype is used to add functions to already created objects. so you first need to have Widgets = {}; then you can do Widgets.prototype.function_name = function() {};

Comment: @Tanatos this gives me error that `Widgets.onFetchComplete` is not a function, like before i get `onFetchComplete` is not a function.

Comment: @Tanatos: First off, I'm not the OP :-) You have completely changed `Widgets` from a "class" to a singleton instance, which is not what you should have. Your understanding of [prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work) seems to be flawed.

Comment: @Bergi, from the code he shared the first time, he didn't post the constructor for Widgets, so I took the fastest way to check my solution.

Comment: Still, he used a `.prototype`, which clearly indicated that a constructor was existent.