# Is there a way to make Bing Translator allow cross-origin network access?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, cross-domain, bing-translator-api

I've created a carousel that pulls in its content via a json feed.  Both the page and the json feed live on the same domain, so I don't have any cross-origin problems with it in the normal view.

However, when translated, Bing Translator blocks the json feeds.  I realize that's pretty much the definition of cross-origin, but I'm wondering if there's a work-around.  We're already using json-p and, of course, we can't edit Bing Translator's web.config.

[Translated page](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?from=&to=es&a=http%3A%2F%2Fqa-www5.coj.net%2Fmayor.aspx) - (microsofttranslator.com)

The error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load (had to delete the json url, due to zilch reputation points). 
>   **Request header field cache-control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.**
>   proxy.ashx?h=VTehD-uzDxRdWce7vbsuVFevSeSl-_M8&a=http%3A%2F%2Fqa-www5.coj.net%2Fmayor.aspx

You can copy and paste the url referenced in the error into a browser window and it comes through fine.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: use getJSON instead of XMLHttpRequest

Comment: try here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410278/xmlhttprequest-json-throws-a-network-error-but-similar-jquery-getjson-code-wo?s=4|1.6202