# jQuery to Javascript Conversion for AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

Looking to convert a jQuery snippet to javascript. Totally hitting a wall with this.

Are there any automated tools for doing this?

The reason we're converting this is because the code is used as part of a product that we're planning on injecting in the future and we can't guarantee that the site has the appropriate (or any) version of jQuery running.

*EDIT: The reason we can't control the use of jQuery is that the customer will be copying and pasting this code themselves. It's highly likely that they will be non-technical and as such not willing/able to setup the appropriate version of jQuery*

This is the jQuery code we're using now:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://api.seedthechange.org/get/?method=getCount&str=suitjamas&jsoncallback=?', function(data) {
          treecount = csn(data[0]); 
          $('span.SeedTheChangeCount').text(treecount); 
      });
})

function csn(val){
    // convert int to comma separated number (1000 -> 1,000)
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
        val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+','+'$2');
    }
    return val;
}
```

**Thanks in advance for any help or tips.**

Comment: why u want to convert it into Javascript? why you can't guarantee that it's running which version if jQuery

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava because we provide this to non-technical people who won't necessarily want to give us direct access to their site to set it up for them.

Comment: yes, but you can check which version of jQuery they are using by inspecting it in Browser if you able to access from internet/intranet

Comment: You could always programmatically check for jQuery and dynamically include it if it's not there. See http://www.sitepoint.com/dynamically-load-jquery-library-javascript/. Otherwise, JSONP is damned tricky

Comment: we're trying to build a business though @ArpitSrivastava and that's just not practical.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're being downvoted. To those having trouble understanding, think of it as the Google Analytics script tag. OP will be distributing a code snippet for people to add to their site

Comment: thanks @Phil, that could definitely be an option. I'm guessing we could use a polyfill of some sort if they have an older version than we need?

Comment: Assuming the API is yours, have you considered opening it up via CORS headers so you don't have to rely on JSONP. Making a straight XHR would be much simpler

Comment: That looks like it could make life a lot easier for us @Phil. It looks like this would be quite easy for our backend guy to do in our Django app. I'm assuming limiting it to GET requests only would be sufficient security protection?

Comment: I'd also take a leaf out of the GA script and put your code in a JS file you host, have them include it and call some functions. See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#quickstart

Answer (score 0):

The best reference for what you ask is: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

In a browser >= IE8 is:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/my/url', true);

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
      // Success!
      var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    } else {
      // Error :(
    }
  }
};

request.send();
request = null;
```

Comment: OP is using JSONP (at the moment) which is an entirely new level of pain

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132796/how-to-make-a-jsonp-request-from-javascript-without-jquery

Comment: I don't know why but I thought it was a lot more complicated. Probably is if you want to handle errors

Answer (score 0):

These are the basic points for conversion: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/from-jquery-to-javascript-a-reference--net-23703

You could write an automated parser that use these rules for conversion. That should do the trick. I am not aware if someone has already done this.