# Not getting JSON response from Twitch.tv api

Tags: angularjs, json, api, twitch

```
var app = angular.module('twitchTV',[]).config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['**']);
});

app.controller('myCtrl',["$scope","$http", function($scope, $http,){
    var api = 'https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/ESL_SC2';

    $http.jsonp(api,{jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback'}, {
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',   
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(function(data) {
      console.log(data.data);
    });
}]);
```

I am not able to get the desired response from the twitch tv api.

Comment: Why are you using `$http.jsonp` is you want a JSON response? JSONP and JSON are very different. `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'` is a response header, is has no place in a request, why do you have it in the request?  `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` says you are sending JSON but you are making a GET request so you aren't sending anything. What do you have that there?

Comment: "I am not able to get the desired response" — What response do you get? What error messages are reported on the Console of your browser's developer tools?

Comment: according to there  documentation `API endpoint support for JSONP has been removed.`  ...   https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api

Comment: @Quentin Object {
  error: "forbidden",
  msg: "unaccepted route: ESL_SC2 - see https://wind-bow.gomix.me/ for infos",
  status: 403
}