# Simple example to retrieve jsonP data from website

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I've seen many examples for `JSONP` but I can't seem to get any to work for my website. It can generate a `JSON` code at some url but I can't retrieve it **from a different domain**. Can you please give me a working example of `JSONP` that can retrieve data **from any `JSON` file** (eg. [www.w3schools.com/json/myTutorials.txt](http://www.w3schools.com/json/myTutorials.txt)).

I may not fully understand, but I just need an explanation, at least, of why if I replace a url with the example above, no data is being pulled.

Comment: The example returns an array of objects so you can use code like: dta = json; len = dta.length; dta[1].display dta[1].url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a modified version of the example in the [jquery docs](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/) using Yahoos public APIs.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
    // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
    dataType: "jsonp",

    // Tell YQL what we want and that we want JSON
    data: {
        q: "show tables",
        format: "json"
    },

    // Work with the response
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
    }
});
```

Along with a jsbin: https://jsbin.com/tuketa/edit?js,output

The reason for the existence of JSONP is to get around the limitations of CORS rules. For security reasons your browser, in general, is only allowed to communicate to the server it loaded the page from. JSONP was created to get around this by giving the server a callback function with which to pad the JSON data, hence the P in JSONP.

As noted in the comments by jasonscript, it's not any server that can function with JSONP, it has to be configured be able to work with JSONP such as the Yahoo API in the example.

Comment: Should probably note that the server must be configured to support JSONP data or your request is not going to work

Answer (score 0):

There's many answers out there pointing out the difference between JSON and JSONP. Your question ("...jsonP that can retrieve...") shows that you didn't fully understand the concept. JSONP is a format of answer, as is HTML, XML, JSON. And so the server that responds the request should be able to send it JSONP formatted.

Answer (score 0):

from a different domain... from any json file... it's not possible. The server response it's actually a javascript that wraps a json object.

jsonP is a protocol. the requester (the javascript in the browser) can't request  via XHR (ajax) outside the source `server:port` due the [Same-Origin-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) (SOP).

To bypass the SOP, JSONP born.

The client does not send a XHR request, instead adds a `<script>` tag to the DOM, with the src attribute pointing to the URL of the jsonP with a parameter (e.g. callback=foo) which tells the name of the local function who receives the JSON as parameter.

Then, the remote server -who understands JSONP- sends a javascript who calls the local function with the JSON as parameter.

Like this example:

#### Client javascript code:

```
function foo(data)
{
    // do stuff with JSON
}

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = '//example.com/path/to/jsonp?callback=foo'

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

(taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6132828/2573335))

#### Server Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/javascript

foo({ "key" : "value" });
```

So, the browser loads the script, calls `foo` with the json as parameter. Now, You have bypassed the SOP restrictions.