# How to make a JSONP request inside a Service Worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

How to make a JSONP request inside a Service Worker?

As you may know, a Service Worker doesn't have `document`. Therefore many javascript approaches like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132796/how-to-make-a-jsonp-request-from-javascript-without-jquery) don't work.

I need to make a JSONP request because the Blogger API doesn't answer requests from different domains using CORS.

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Web Worker global has a method called [importScripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts), which you can use to include script urls.

So just define a callback function, use the function name as the `callback` url parameter and pass the url to `importScripts`

**webworker.js**

```
function cb(data){
    console.log(data);
}

importScripts('http://example.com/jsonp.php?callback=cb');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! (I've used `self.cb = function (resp) { }`)

Comment: It looks like as of Chrome 71, runtime calls to `importScripts` are not allowed:

"Prior to Chrome 71, calling importScripts() asynchronously outside of the install handler would work. Starting with Chrome 71, those calls throw a runtime exception (unless the same URL was previously imported in an install handler), matching the behavior in other browsers."

-- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/10/tweaks-to-addAll-importScripts