# How to convert object in array js

Tags: javascript, json

I very new to programming and I can't find the solution of my issue, can you give me the solution please?

I have this JSON file:

```
{
  "groups": "[{ id: 1, title: 'group 1' }, { id: 2, title: 'group 2' }]"
}
```

And I need something like this in my js (but i want import my JSON to get array like this) :

```
const groups = [{ id: 1, title: 'group 1' }, { id: 2, title: 'group 2' }]
```

I don't know how to do without using jQuery.

I already tried with this:

```
const json = require('./test.json');
```

This code returns an object: [image: screen of what is returned]

It's almost what I want but it didn't work when I use it in my code because I don't want an object but and array like I said above.

How can achieve this?

Comment: You are looking for `JSON.parse(json.groups)`

Comment: I feel I am missing something, you just want JSON.parse?

Comment: This is a JSON encoded string inside a JSON file. It makes little sense to have `"` around the value associated with `groups`, I'd expect to not have them, so it's just `"groups": [{ id: 1, title: 'group 1' }, { id: 2, title: 'group 2' }]` to begin with. At any rate, you can convert that using `JSON.parse(obj.groups)`

Comment: jQuery is irrelevant. First you need to parse the string containing the array; naming the constant itself is trivial, but if you want it named the same thing as in your object, that's a different kettle of fish.

Comment: @Weedoze no need for the `JSON.parse` bit.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir the value is JSON, so without parsing it, you won't get an array.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir It's a string, so if you want an object, you'll need to parse it.

Comment: I think he meant at that point, just modify your JSON file and don't put the "" around the array. @DaveNewton

Comment: JSON.parse is not working

Comment: `{"groups":[{"id":1,"title":"group 1"},{"id":2,"title":"group 2"}]}` Try that in https://jsonlint.com/. Then compare with yours.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dwjBdb

Comment: @DaveNewton `require` on a json file [**automatically** parses the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35389622/9867451).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir A string value there is perfectly legal-you're suggesting it guesses what you intended?

Answer (score 3):

The value of `groups` is not valid JSON: string values should be surrounded by double-quote marks, and so should keys. The file with valid JSON in that string would look like this:

```
{
  "groups": "[{ \"id\": 1, \"title\": \"group 1\" }, { \"id\": 2, \"title\": \"group 2\" }]"
}
```

Of course if you have control over the creation of this file, it would be better to have this value as part of the native JSON content, rather than JSON-in-a-string-inside-JSON. If that's not possible, you will need to correct the quoting in the string yourself, which can be done with a couple of Regular Expression replacements.

```
/* obj is the object in the JSON file */
var json_str = obj.groups.replace(/'/g,"\"").replace(/([a-z]+)\:/g,"\"$1\":");
var groups = JSON.parse(json_str);
```

Alternatively, although the string is not valid JSON it is a valid Javascript expression, so **if the contents of the file are trustworthy,** you can also do it with `eval:`

```
var groups = eval(obj.groups);
```

Comment: Almost, but you don't need to escape slashes or replace. Working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dwjBdb

Comment: @suncat100 I'm not sure what you mean? Double-quotes within a single-quoted string don't need backslash-escaping, but a single-quoted string is not valid JSON, so the asker's file can't be changed in that way and still be a valid JSON file. My answer shows how to convert the string into valid JSON so it can be fed into `JSON.parse()`, or how to sidestep that requirement using `eval()`. Your example starts with an already-corrected version of the JSON string, so you are jumping ahead.

Comment: Sure. I see now you have explained this in your post. Of course, the ultimate fix to his question is to actually fix his JSON first ... After all, the point of JSON in the first place is structuring data for code, and he added his data into a "string" instead. When structured properly, it will transmit correctly to JS with little effort.

Comment: The asker hasn't said whether he has control over the content of the JSON file. I'm guessing he does not, but have addressed in my answer what he can do if he does (2nd para).

Answer (score 0):

I just need to fill my array "groups" like that :

```
[{ id: 1, title: 'group 1' }, { id: 2, title: 'group 2' }]
```

with a json file and without jquery

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't notice the "without jQuery" in the original question, here is a new answer:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', './test.json', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    // Success!
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
  } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

  }
};
```

It does two things:
 1. Loads the json file
 2. Parses the loaded string into a javascript object.

Answer (score -1):

if you can't edit original text, you need replace ' to " and then did `JSON.parse(json.groups)`;

otherwise you can change a little your json like this:

```
JSON.parse('[{ "id": 1, "title": "group 1" }, { "id": 2, "title": "group 2" }]')
```

be careful with " and ' parentheses

```
{
  "key":"string"
}
```

string with defined with ' parentheses not valid

in JSON keys must be to in "" parentheses

Comment: i did but i have this error now Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: because you need ' to "

Comment: i juste past your json in my json and still have the error

Comment: sorry fix to JSON.parse('[{ "id": 1, "title": "group 1" }, { "id": 2, "title": "group 2" }]')

Answer (score -1):

Before you can even do anything with your JSON file, you need to load it. jQuery has a shortcut, which will even automatically parse the JSON-string into a native JS object for you:

```
$.getJSON('./test.json', function(data) {
  console.dir(data);
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: i said without jquery ^^

Comment: Ok sorry. In either case, you need to do TWO things: 1) Load the file by Ajax (XMLHttpRequest), 2) JSON.parse(the_loaded_data). Unfortunately, without jQuery, the AJAX request is much longer. The answer is basically here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35294633/what-is-the-vanilla-js-version-of-jquerys-getjson

There is no way around those two tasks.

Answer (score -2):

You can parse the object to an array this way:

`Object.values(YOUR_OBJECT)`

docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/values

Comment: This would not actually produce what OP is looking for. If `YOUR_OBJECT` is the content of the file, then you'd just get an array with a single *string* describing an array. If it's the value of the `groups` key, then it's going to produce (essentially) gibberish, as you're getting the values for all keys off a string.

Comment: Oh, i didn't noticed that :S