# Cordova InAppBrowser executeScript() not firing callback in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I have a cordova app and using InAppBrowser to login to a website. On Successful login, I need to pass the response to the App. I am using executeScript() to achieve and the same is working fine in Android, whereas in iOS, the callback for executeScript() is not getting fired.

My Load stop event listener is as follows

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open("XXXX.html", "_blank", 'location=yes,toolbar=yes');


function iabLoadStop(event) {
    alert("EXECUTING SCRIPT")
    ref.executeScript({
        code: "document.body.innerHTML"
    }, function(values) {
        alert("SCRIPT EXECUTED")
        alert(values)
    });
}
```

I am getting "EXECUTING SCRIPT" alert successfully on load stop event, but the executeScript() which was support to alert "SCRIPT EXECUTED" and the innerHTML is not getting fired.

Comment: You can also use JSONP to call iabLoadStop. These links help you do handle JSONP-responses on the [client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6132828/2401386) and [server (php)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6809069/2401386).

Comment: My issue is not on iabLoadStop is getting called. iabLoadStop was trigerred successfully, but the CB for executeScript() is not getting fired.

Comment: Can you provide the code within XXXX.html to show of how this CB is called, please.

Comment: The code inside XXXX.html is a JSON as text { success: true } which is getting successfully alerted in Android, but not getting fired in iOS.

Comment: Have you also tried to remove the first alert within iabLoadStop? As this function stops the programm-flow and might prevent executeScript to work correctly on iOS.

Comment: @Blauharley Looks like the first alert() was indeed the reason as it stopped execution of the further functions. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out the reason was with the first `alert`. This function stops the programm-flow but also caused the code within `XXXX.html`, that is executed by `executeScript`, to stop.

So it should be avoided to call such functions (`alert`/`confirm` etc.) between event `loadstop` and `executeScript`, at least on iOS. There are alternatives like `console.log`.