# Get Squarespace Collection items with HTTP

Tags: http, get, squarespace

I am trying to get content from a Squarespace blog collection to display on an alternate platform, an app. Is there a way to do this with HTTP requests? I have NOT enabled developer mode in an effort to keep the site template live.

For example,  if there were a blog collection with 5 posts in it, I would like to receive a GET response that contains the data of those 5 posts to display on the app.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all Squarespace collections and items can be [requested as JSON](https://developers.squarespace.com/view-json-data) (though not all *content* is always available as JSON, [such as open-block fields](https://developers.squarespace.com/open-block-field/)) by using the `format=json` or `format=json-pretty` parameters.

For example, here is the JSON version of the official Squarespace Blog:

https://blog.squarespace.com/?format=json

Since the information is available as JSON, it becomes a question of how you make your request. If it's being handled in the browser, you'd likely make use of [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132796/how-to-make-a-jsonp-request-from-javascript-without-jquery).

Once you successfully request and receive the data, it is then a question of parsing and rendering the properties you need.

For example, you might first look at the `items` array, which contains a list of the items/posts in the collection (up to the maximum per-page limit; take note of the `pagination` property). You can then loop over the array of items, obtain the `body` property or other properties you need, and do with the data as needed. You could also utilize the `fullUrl` property to make subsequent requests to individual item URLs, appending `?format=json` accordingly, as needed.

Understand that the content within the `body` property is likely to be full of Squarespace-specific markup.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much for your help. Now I have to figure out how to grab the content in the body to render in the app which will take some time haha

Comment: Sorry about that. Accepted!