# Odd URL Callback performance. How do It know?

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm studying very [closely a YQL query example.](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-tutorials.html#tutorial-first_yql_app)  There is a html script call to an API url address with callback function identified.

If I include the callback as a separate `<script></script>` things work fine. It totally fails if the code is contained in a single `<script></script>` tag.

This works:

```
<script>
  function top_stories(o) {
    var items = o.query.results.item;
    var output = '';
    var no_items = items.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < no_items; i++) {
      var title = items[i].title;
      var link = items[i].link;
      var desc = items[i].description;
      output += "<h3><a href='" + link + "'>" + title + "</a></h3>" + desc + "<hr/>";
    }
    // Place news stories in div tag
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = output;
  }
</script>

<script src='https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20rss%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Frss.news.yahoo.com%2Frss%2Ftopstories%22&format=json&callback=top_stories'></script>
```

While this next bit fails to function at all.

```
  <script>
      function top_stories(o) {
        var items = o.query.results.item;
        (... same as above)
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = output;
      }

      src='https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20rss%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Frss.news.yahoo.com%2Frss%2Ftopstories%22&format=json&callback=top_stories';
</script>
```

Non functional jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ogcoaaff/

Swap a few comments and success:  https://jsfiddle.net/ogcoaaff/1/

I don't believe this is a timing / loading sequence issue.  No way. I was pretty careful to push the scripts into the jsfiddle HTML box and not the script box.  I did not want to use jQuery and have that cloud the discussion.

Can someone explain what's going on here?  What am I missing?  (Note: I was hoping to run a quick call to a YQL api from totally within a javascript file in another application where I don't have access to `<script>` calls. (and where I can't use $.JSON and prefer not to use XMLHttpRequest().)

I'd just really would like to understand what is happening here. Anybody know the details (or better yet, a tech reference explaining this behavior?)

Many thanks.

Comment: Your "nonfunctional" example is simply invalid syntax. You can't just drop a src attribute into the middle of a script block and expect it to work.

Comment: Attribute?  I thought that was a simple `var`.    aaargh!  clean up that comment, voice it as an answer, include this link and I'll accept it...   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: No worries, looks like robertklep got there first :) (on rereading my comment sounds a lot snippier than I intended, sorry about that)

Comment: No offense taken, none what so ever.  In hindsight I totally muffed that one up  :^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<script>` element has two relatively distinct uses:

1. Load external JavaScript:

   ```
   <script src="URL"></script>
   ```
2. Embed a piece of JavaScript:

   ```
   <script>
     // code here
   </script>
   ```

Your working example uses both of these uses: one to embed a script into the page (containing the `top_stories` function), and one to retrieve an external script from Yahoo.

Your non-working example is, simply put, just invalid. The `src` part is an *attribute* of the `<script>` element, so it can only be used with the `<script ....>` block.

Don't be tempted to think that mixing them properly will work, though:

```
<script src="URL">
  // code here
</script>
```

This won't work, or at least won't work reliably (I believe that this isn't even allowed according to the HTML standard).

> I was hoping to run a quick call to a YQL api from totally within a javascript file in another application where I don't have access to `<script>` calls.

You can programmatically create `<script>` elements. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132796/how-to-make-a-jsonp-request-from-javascript-without-jquery) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907777/making-and-handling-jsonp-request-using-javascript) to get an idea on how that would work.